# Installing latest updates for my RTM sharepoint 2016 server

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, configuration, 2016, farm

I am working on new sharepoint server 2016 . currently our customer installed the sharepoint around 6 months ago, and seems they did not even configure the farm. currently they are on **16.0.4351.1000** which represents RTM. and i want to install the latest updates which is currently for March 2017 as mentioned on this link http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Builds/SharePoint-2016-Builds.aspx

But i have the following questions:-

1. is it better to configure the farm first (current farm build number is **16.0.4351.1000**) then install the latest updates? OR i can install the latest updates then configure the farm?
2. Unlike sharepoint 2013, seems there are 2 updates one for `Language Independent Files` and the other for `Language Dependent Files`.. so which one i should install ?and why ?

thanks

Thanks

Comment: If the farm "isn't configured" how are the users "using" it?  Also, you apply both the language independent (sts) and the appropriate language dependent (wss) patch.

Comment: @GregW no users are using it currently ... seems they have install it , but they did not start working on it.. for applying the language patch should i install one before the other? and should i run the product configuration wizard after each installation ?

Comment: If your customer installed the servers themselves and do not know how to get the farm going, i would make sure that everything is set up correctly before starting to think about patching/configuring it.

Comment: And for reference:  apply the patch files, then run psconfig

Comment: @Christoffer Yes the installation is done correctly.... now i can access the central administration without any problem,,also i can create new site collections,,  but for example there is only 2 managed services created ( application discovery and security token).. so they have installed the sharepoint server correctly ,, but still i need to configure it from "Central administration" >> "Configuration Wizard" ...

Comment: @GregW and what about configuring the farm from "Central administration" >> "Configuration Wizard" should i do it before or after installing the patches or it will be the same ??

Comment: Unless the Config Wizard has changed in 2016, avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @GregW why it will help me in getting things done for me ,,, instead of having to create everything myself,, like search service, excel services, etc..

Comment: Last advice I had received (still trying to find the blog post) was that it resulted in a broken farm, depending on the options chosen and, if you're like me, hate the fact that all the databases it creates have GUIDs in their names.

Comment: As Grew W mentions, avoid the wizard at all costs, GUIDS on the db's and services is hell to work with using PowerShell. Still, i would check that all the services accounts is set up correctly, SQL permissions, minimum required ram, disks etc.

Comment: The AutoSPInstaller may be a good start to get your farm configured:  https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com.  It'll skip the install steps as it's already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As farm is not configured then best way is install the latest updates then configure it.
2. Yes there is change in sharepoint 2016 patching, For SP 2016 MSFT release two files every month. You have to install both files (any order, does not matter).

After this configure the farm.

Comment: so you prefer  not to configure the farm from "Central administration" >> "Configuration Wizard"  and to first install the patches, run the product configuration wizard, then configure the farm from "Central administration" >> "Configuration Wizard"  ??

Comment: Looks like you already ran the SP product config wizard which create the config db and central admin. So farm is there, central admin config wizard basically create new service application / web application....even though, i would install the updates first then configure the remaining parts

Comment: but in my case there is only one content database for the central admin site .. but i have the central administration site created correctly ..

Comment: yes, that is what you get when you ran SharePoint Product configuration wizard...a config DB and a Central admin db...after that you have to configured the services application, web application...you can use either farm wizard from central admin or manually create them...as you have nothing in the farm then it is best time to apply the updates

Comment: now i follow all the steps where i download and install the latest sharepoint updates, run the product configuration wizard, but after that i checked my farm build number and it showed the following 16.0.4507.1000 which is not listed under the farm build numbers for sharepoint 2016 http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Builds/SharePoint-2016-Builds.aspx

Comment: also when i checked the build version from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\16.0\BuildVersion i got this number 16.0.4351.1000..

Comment: It really doesnot matter, what you have to do...go to Central admin > upgrade and migration > Check product and patch installation status ...on this page look for KB 3178672& KB 3178675....if you see any of this says installed then you all set